# Bash script run with timeout won't exit on SIGINT

Tags: bash, shell, timeout

I have a bash script which calls another bash script within a for loop (under a timeout condition) in the following format:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'trap - SIGTERM && kill 0' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
INNER_SCRIPT_PATH="./inner_script.sh"

for file in "$SAMPLEDIR"/*
do
  if [[ "${file: -4}" == ".csv"  ]]; then 
    CSVPATH="$file"
    CSVNAME=${CSVPATH##*/} # extract file name
    CSVNAME=${CSVNAME%.*} # remove extension
    timeout -k 10s 30m bash "$INNER_SCRIPT_PATH" 
  fi 
done
wait
```

Pressing Ctrl-C does not quit out of all the processes, and I have a feeling there is probably something wrong with the way I'm calling the inner bash script here (especially with timeout). Would appreciate feedback on how to make this better!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is with the `timeout` command, that makes your script immune to Ctrl+C invocation. Since by default `timeout` runs in its own process group and *not* in the foreground process group, it is immune to the signals invoked from an interactive terminal.

You can run it with `--foreground` to accept signals from an interactive shell. See [timeout Man page](https://ss64.com/bash/timeout.html)

Comment: Thanks! To clarify, will simply adding `--foreground` after `timeout` be sufficient?

Comment: @V.Doe: Should be! You can test it for your case

Comment: This will make timeout susceptible to Ctrl+C, but won't kill any children process. Would be great to have both features

Comment: @PabloBianchi are you sure it doesn't kill children processes? I'm reading the docs, and it says, that `children of COMMAND will not be timed out` - What exactly does that mean?

It feels like if children are not killed that could cause SERIOUS issues.